# Multiple imputation: Pooling t statistics

Tags: missing-data, multiple-imputation

I have conducted analyses to compare dependent correlations (Steiger, 1980) using multiply imputed data. The statistics follow a t distribution.

Question: What is the correct way to pool these statistics, with the goal of generating a p-value?

Here is what the results look like (from 20 imputations): -2.938462 -2.627696 -2.562013 -2.354825 -2.542520 -2.442978 -2.583879 -2.421124 -2.746131 -2.936789 -2.328653 -2.884968 -2.423605 -2.567752 -1.787200 -2.675324 -2.815900 -2.307922 -2.968579 -2.299145

Comment: What is your question and what is the design of the experiment? Also, can you post a sample of your data?

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the following paper, it talks about conducting inference when you have multiply imputed data.

> Schafer, J. L. (1999). Multiple imputation: a primer. Statistical
>   Methods in Medical Research, 8(1):3-15.